# How do I create function that runs a command?

Tags: linux, powershell-core, powershell-v6.0

So what I'm trying to do is recreate a similar function as I would use in Bash, but in Powershell:

```
yell() { echo "$0: $*" >&2; }
die() { yell "$*"; exit 111; }
try() { "$@" || die "FAILED: $*"; }
```

The part that I'm most interested at the moment is the try() function here. Essentially what it does is allow me to wrap a command with this function and let it manage the exit code. The effect is something like this:

```
try doSomething -args
```

If `doSomething` exits with a non-zero, it will output the command to stderr and stop the script from executing.

I realize that Powershell has an error action that can be used to abort scripts, but it seems that it only applies to commandlets. I need something that I can use on anything throughout the script. I'm also looking to avoid tons of verbose try/catch logic crudding up the script, hence the desire for something elegant like try/yell/die. This way, I can write the handling in this function alone and just use it to call anything that I want handled.

I found `$MyInvocation` and figured that this might be the way in, but I can't seem to find a way to actually execute it from within the function. For example:

```
function run() {
    $MyInvocation # ?? what do??
}

run doSomething -args
```

I think I can figure out the rest on my own, I just don't quite know how to write this wrapper function. Any ideas?

### Update

So I did something kind of cheesy and I substringed the command and did an `Invoke-Expression` on what was left and it seems to work. It feels super hacky, so I'm still open to ideas:

```
function attempt() {
    $thisCommand = $MyInvocation.Line.Trim()
    Write-Output $thisCommand
    Invoke-Expression $thisCommand.Substring(8)
    if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { 
        throw "Command failed $thisCommand" 
        exit 111
    }
}

attempt doSomething -args
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function to run an arbitrary command and throw an error if that command fails you could do something like this:

```
function Test-Command {
    try {
        $cmd, $params = $args
        $params = @($params)
        $global:LastExitCode = 0
        $output = & $cmd @params 2>&1
        if ($global:LastExitCode -ne 0) {
            throw $output
        }
        $output
    } catch {
        throw $_
    }
}
```

Breakdown:

`$cmd, $params = $args` takes the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#args) `$args` (an array of the arguments passed to the function) and assigns its first element to the variable `$cmd` and the rest to the variable `$params`.

`$params = @($params)` ensures that `$params` contains an array (required for the next step), even if the variable was empty or held just a single value.

`& $cmd @params` invokes the command using the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) `&` while [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) the parameters. [Do **NOT** use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

The [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-3.0) `2>&1` merges error output with normal output, so that both output streams are captured in the variable `$output`.

If `$cmd` is a *PowerShell cmdlet* errors will throw an exception, which is caught by the [`try`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-3.0) statement. The rest of the code in the `try` block will then be skipped. Note, however, that not all errors thrown by PowerShell cmdlets are automatically terminating errors (see for instance [*"An Introduction to Error Handling in PowerShell"*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/) on the Scripting Guy blog). To turn non-terminating errors into terminating ones you need to set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` (and reset it to its original value after you're done).

If `$cmd` is an *external command* errors will not throw exceptions, but the automatic variable [`$LastExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#lastexitcode) is updated with the exit code of the command. A command returning a non-zero exit code will trigger the `if` condition and cause a custom exception to be thrown, using the command output as the exception message. That exception is then also caught by the `try` statement. The rest of the code in the `try` block is skipped again.

`$global:LastExitCode = 0` resets the variable `$LastExitCode` before each run. That is necessary because only external commands return an exit code, whereas PowerShell cmdlets do not. Since `$LastExitCode` preserves the exit code of the external command last run in the current session, not resetting the variable would fudge the status detection of a PowerShell cmdlet run after an external command.

The last line in the `try` block, which echoes the captured command output, is only reached if the command neither throws an exception nor returns a non-zero exit code.

Any caught exception is handled in the `catch` block, which simply passes the exception to the caller of the function. Instead of throwing you could also output the error and exit, of course.

Comment: When I test this with `Test-Command echo foo` it seems to run the command once for every character in "foo" so I get 'f' 'o' 'o' each on a separate line. This seems to be true for most commands. For example `Test-Command dotnet --info` doesn't work either because it thinks that each dash is an argument

Comment: I'm assuming I'm calling this wrong. Does this require me to send parameters in as a hash table?

Comment: Oh I see that it'll work if I'm invoking a powershell function through it. Is there a way to make this work with other commands though?

Comment: FWIW neither `$global:LastExitCode` nor `$LASTEXITCODE` seem to work in PWSH in an actual linux environment. I've had to use `$?` instead which returns true/false on whether or not the last exit code was a success code.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Your question didn't mention that you intend to run this on Linux, so I tested the code only on my Windows test box. Please do not omit relevant details like that from your questions.

Comment: I was developing the scripts on windows so everything was working until I deployed it to the build server. I'm mentioning it here because I was also blindsided by it. I wouldn't assume powershell would behave differently for something so common. I'm simply noting it here. At any rate, it is now in the tags.

Comment: So one thing that I noticed is that if i send a cli command to the function defined here, the output of that command is not printed to the console :/

Comment: Worked just fine for me (e.g. `Test-Command ping 127.0.0.1`).